# Farm Clicker game - Gold's value is increasing more than necessary

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a Farm Clicker game myself with Javascript. (In other words, as you click the Add Gold button, the user earns 1 gold and can obtain passive gold by buying some animals according to the number of gold he has.) But there is a problem with the program: If I save 50 gold and buy a goat, the gold suddenly increases more than necessary. The problem is most likely in the section that says setInterval, but I still couldn't find the exact solution.

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <title>Farm clicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
// global variables
const myContent = document.getElementById("content");
var gold=0;
let animals = {};
var goldToAdd = 0;
// global functions

function addGoldButton() {
  let myButton = document.createElement("button");
  myButton.id = "addButton";
  myButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>addGold(1)); // add one
  myButton.innerHTML = "Add Gold!";
  myContent.appendChild(myButton);
}



addGoldButton();
function addGold(goldToAdd) {
  console.trace();
  if (gold == 0) {
    gold = goldToAdd;
    let goldCounter = document.createElement("h2");
    goldCounter.id = "goldCounter";
    goldCounter.innerHTML = "Gold: " + gold;
    myContent.appendChild(goldCounter);
  } else
  {
    gold += goldToAdd;
    document.getElementById("goldCounter").innerHTML = "Gold: " + gold;
  }
  // check for events on current gold level
  checkGold();
  goldToAdd=0;
}

function checkGold(){
  if (gold >= 50 && document.getElementById("goatBuyButton") == null) {
    let buttonBar = document.createElement("div");
    buttonBar.id = "buttonBar";
    let buyButton = document.createElement("button");
    buyButton.id = "goatBuyButton";
    buyButton.innerHTML = "Buy Goat (50g)";
    buyButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>buyAnimal("goat"));
    myContent.appendChild(buttonBar);
    buttonBar.appendChild(buyButton);
  }

  if (gold >= 90 && document.getElementById("pigBuyButton") == null) {
    let buttonBar = document.getElementById("buttonBar");
    let buyButton = document.createElement("button");
    buyButton.id = "pigBuyButton";
    buyButton.innerHTML = "Buy Pig (90g)";
    buyButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>buyAnimal("pig"));
    buttonBar.appendChild(buyButton);
  }

  if (gold >= 120 && document.getElementById("cowBuyButton") == null){
    buttonBar = document.getElementById("buttonBar");
    let buyButton = document.createElement("button");
    buyButton.id = "cowBuyButton";
    buyButton.innerHTML = "Buy Cow (120g)";
    buyButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>buyAnimal("cow"));

    buttonBar.appendChild(buyButton);
}

function buyAnimal(animal) {
  let itemBar = document.getElementById('itemBar');
  if (itemBar == null) {
    itemBar = document.createElement("div");
    itemBar.id = "itemBar";
    myContent.appendChild(itemBar);
  }

  switch (animal) {
    case "":
      //do something, don't and forget the break;
    case "goat":
      if (gold >= 50) {
        addGold(-50);
        if (animals.goats == null) {
          animals.goats = 1;
          let myElement = document.createElement("div");
          myElement.id = "goats";
          myElement.innerHTML = "Goat Quantity: " + animals.goats;
          itemBar.appendChild(myElement);
        } else {
          animals.goats += 1;
          document.getElementById("goats").innerHTML = "Goat Quantity: " + animals.goats;
        }
      }
      break;
    case "pig":
      if (gold >= 90) {
        addGold(-90);
        if (animals.pigs == null) {
          animals.pigs = 1;
          let myElement = document.createElement("div");
          myElement.id = "pigs";
          myElement.innerHTML = "Pig Quantity: " + animals.pigs;
          itemBar.appendChild(myElement);
        } else {
          animals.pigs += 1;
          document.getElementById("pigs").innerHTML = "Pig Quantity: " + animals.pigs;
        }
      }
      break;
    case "cow":
      if (gold >= 120) {
        addGold(-120);
        if (animals.cows == null) {
          animals.cows = 1;
          let myElement = document.createElement("div");
          myElement.id = "cows";
          myElement.innerHTML = "Cow Quantity: " + animals.cows;
          itemBar.appendChild(myElement);
        } else {
          animals.cows += 1;
          document.getElementById("cows").innerHTML = "Cow Quantity: " + animals.cows;
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
      console.log("no animal found");
  }
}
function passiveGold() {

  if (animals.goats > 0) {
    goldToAdd += animals.goats*5; //50=>5 10=>1
  }
  if (animals.pigs > 0) {
    goldToAdd += animals.pigs*10; //90=>10  9=>1
  }
  if (animals.cows > 0) {
    goldToAdd += animals.cows*15; //120=>15 8=>1
  }
  addGold(goldToAdd);
}
setInterval(passiveGold, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues with the gold incrementation here. There's a brace out of place leading to (I think) the setInterval be created several times (each time `checkGold` is called, in fact). Secondly, the `goldToAdd` amount is not zero at the start of `passiveGold`. I've also edited `addGold` so that two gold counters don't turn up when you hit 0 gold. Snippet below:

```js
const myContent = document.getElementById("content");
var gold=0;
let animals = {};
var goldToAdd = 0;
// global functions

function addGoldButton() {
  let myButton = document.createElement("button");
  myButton.id = "addButton";
  myButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>addGold(1)); // add one
  myButton.innerHTML = "Add Gold!";
  myContent.appendChild(myButton);
}


addGoldButton();

function addGold(goldToAdd) {
  if(document.getElementById("goldCounter") == null) {
    let goldCounter = document.createElement("h2");
    goldCounter.id = "goldCounter";
    myContent.appendChild(goldCounter);
  }
  
  gold += goldToAdd;
  document.getElementById("goldCounter").innerHTML = "Gold: " + gold;
  
  checkGold();
}

function checkGold(){
  if (gold >= 50 && document.getElementById("goatBuyButton") == null) {
    let buttonBar = document.createElement("div");
    buttonBar.id = "buttonBar";
    let buyButton = document.createElement("button");
    buyButton.id = "goatBuyButton";
    buyButton.innerHTML = "Buy Goat (50g)";
    buyButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>buyAnimal("goat"));
    myContent.appendChild(buttonBar);
    buttonBar.appendChild(buyButton);
  }

  if (gold >= 90 && document.getElementById("pigBuyButton") == null) {
    let buttonBar = document.getElementById("buttonBar");
    let buyButton = document.createElement("button");
    buyButton.id = "pigBuyButton";
    buyButton.innerHTML = "Buy Pig (90g)";
    buyButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>buyAnimal("pig"));
    buttonBar.appendChild(buyButton);
  }

  if (gold >= 120 && document.getElementById("cowBuyButton") == null){
    buttonBar = document.getElementById("buttonBar");
    let buyButton = document.createElement("button");
    buyButton.id = "cowBuyButton";
    buyButton.innerHTML = "Buy Cow (120g)";
    buyButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>buyAnimal("cow"));

    buttonBar.appendChild(buyButton);
  }
}

function buyAnimal(animal) {
  let itemBar = document.getElementById('itemBar');
  if (itemBar == null) {
    itemBar = document.createElement("div");
    itemBar.id = "itemBar";
    myContent.appendChild(itemBar);
  }

  switch (animal) {
    case "":
      //do something, don't and forget the break;
    case "goat":
      if (gold >= 50) {
        addGold(-50);
        if (animals.goats == null) {
          animals.goats = 1;
          let myElement = document.createElement("div");
          myElement.id = "goats";
          myElement.innerHTML = "Goat Quantity: " + animals.goats;
          itemBar.appendChild(myElement);
        } else {
          animals.goats += 1;
          document.getElementById("goats").innerHTML = "Goat Quantity: " + animals.goats;
        }
      }
      break;
    case "pig":
      if (gold >= 90) {
        addGold(-90);
        if (animals.pigs == null) {
          animals.pigs = 1;
          let myElement = document.createElement("div");
          myElement.id = "pigs";
          myElement.innerHTML = "Pig Quantity: " + animals.pigs;
          itemBar.appendChild(myElement);
        } else {
          animals.pigs += 1;
          document.getElementById("pigs").innerHTML = "Pig Quantity: " + animals.pigs;
        }
      }
      break;
    case "cow":
      if (gold >= 120) {
        addGold(-120);
        if (animals.cows == null) {
          animals.cows = 1;
          let myElement = document.createElement("div");
          myElement.id = "cows";
          myElement.innerHTML = "Cow Quantity: " + animals.cows;
          itemBar.appendChild(myElement);
        } else {
          animals.cows += 1;
          document.getElementById("cows").innerHTML = "Cow Quantity: " + animals.cows;
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
      console.log("no animal found");
  }
}
function passiveGold() {
  goldToAdd = 0;
  if (animals.goats > 0) {
    goldToAdd += animals.goats*5; //50=>5 10=>1
  }
  if (animals.pigs > 0) {
    goldToAdd += animals.pigs*10; //90=>10  9=>1
  }
  if (animals.cows > 0) {
    goldToAdd += animals.cows*15; //120=>15 8=>1
  }
  addGold(goldToAdd);
}
setInterval(passiveGold, 10000);
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So here the problem is in the `passiveGold Function`.It runs in to a infinite loop because after you are buying an animal the animal count is obviously greater than 0.So the `if condition` will be evaluated to **true always** inside the passiveGold function and as a result of that it runs into a infinite loop.

```
function passiveGold() {

  if (animals.goats > 0) {
    goldToAdd += animals.goats*5; //50=>5 10=>1
    return;
  }
  if (animals.pigs > 0) {
    goldToAdd += animals.pigs*10; //90=>10  9=>1
    return;
  }
  if (animals.cows > 0) {
    goldToAdd += animals.cows*15; //120=>15 8=>1
    return;
  }
  addGold(goldToAdd);
  
}
```

So here i just did a small modification by adding return statements into every if condition code blocks.So that after executing once it will return to the main function.

```js
// global variables
const myContent = document.getElementById("content");
var gold=0;
let animals = {};
var goldToAdd = 0;
// global functions

function addGoldButton() {
  let myButton = document.createElement("button");
  myButton.id = "addButton";
  myButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>addGold(1)); // add one
  myButton.innerHTML = "Add Gold!";
  myContent.appendChild(myButton);
}



addGoldButton();
function addGold(goldToAdd) {
  console.trace();
  if (gold == 0) {
    gold = goldToAdd;
    let goldCounter = document.createElement("h2");
    goldCounter.id = "goldCounter";
    goldCounter.innerHTML = "Gold: " + gold;
    myContent.appendChild(goldCounter);
  } else
  {
    gold += goldToAdd;
    document.getElementById("goldCounter").innerHTML = "Gold: " + gold;
  }
  // check for events on current gold level
  checkGold();
  goldToAdd=0;
}

function checkGold(){
  if (gold >= 50 && document.getElementById("goatBuyButton") == null) {
    let buttonBar = document.createElement("div");
    buttonBar.id = "buttonBar";
    let buyButton = document.createElement("button");
    buyButton.id = "goatBuyButton";
    buyButton.innerHTML = "Buy Goat (50g)";
    buyButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>buyAnimal("goat"));
    myContent.appendChild(buttonBar);
    buttonBar.appendChild(buyButton);
  }

  if (gold >= 90 && document.getElementById("pigBuyButton") == null) {
    let buttonBar = document.getElementById("buttonBar");
    let buyButton = document.createElement("button");
    buyButton.id = "pigBuyButton";
    buyButton.innerHTML = "Buy Pig (90g)";
    buyButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>buyAnimal("pig"));
    buttonBar.appendChild(buyButton);
  }

  if (gold >= 120 && document.getElementById("cowBuyButton") == null){
    buttonBar = document.getElementById("buttonBar");
    let buyButton = document.createElement("button");
    buyButton.id = "cowBuyButton";
    buyButton.innerHTML = "Buy Cow (120g)";
    buyButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>buyAnimal("cow"));

    buttonBar.appendChild(buyButton);
}

function buyAnimal(animal) {
  let itemBar = document.getElementById('itemBar');
  if (itemBar == null) {
    itemBar = document.createElement("div");
    itemBar.id = "itemBar";
    myContent.appendChild(itemBar);
  }

  switch (animal) {
    case "":
      //do something, don't and forget the break;
    case "goat":
      if (gold >= 50) {
        addGold(-50);
        if (animals.goats == null) {
          animals.goats = 1;
          let myElement = document.createElement("div");
          myElement.id = "goats";
          myElement.innerHTML = "Goat Quantity: " + animals.goats;
          itemBar.appendChild(myElement);
        } else {
          animals.goats += 1;
          document.getElementById("goats").innerHTML = "Goat Quantity: " + animals.goats;
        }
      }
      break;
    case "pig":
      if (gold >= 90) {
        addGold(-90);
        if (animals.pigs == null) {
          animals.pigs = 1;
          let myElement = document.createElement("div");
          myElement.id = "pigs";
          myElement.innerHTML = "Pig Quantity: " + animals.pigs;
          itemBar.appendChild(myElement);
        } else {
          animals.pigs += 1;
          document.getElementById("pigs").innerHTML = "Pig Quantity: " + animals.pigs;
        }
      }
      break;
    case "cow":
      if (gold >= 120) {
        addGold(-120);
        if (animals.cows == null) {
          animals.cows = 1;
          let myElement = document.createElement("div");
          myElement.id = "cows";
          myElement.innerHTML = "Cow Quantity: " + animals.cows;
          itemBar.appendChild(myElement);
        } else {
          animals.cows += 1;
          document.getElementById("cows").innerHTML = "Cow Quantity: " + animals.cows;
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
      console.log("no animal found");
  }
}
function passiveGold() {

  if (animals.goats > 0) {
    goldToAdd += animals.goats*5; //50=>5 10=>1
    return;
  }
  if (animals.pigs > 0) {
    goldToAdd += animals.pigs*10; //90=>10  9=>1
    return;
  }
  if (animals.cows > 0) {
    goldToAdd += animals.cows*15; //120=>15 8=>1
    return;
  }
  addGold(goldToAdd);
  
}
setInterval(passiveGold, 10000);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Farm clicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Hope I solved your problem.And if you need anything to be clarified let me know.

Comment: When I click on the buy goat button and then the add gold button, the h2 element is created at the bottom once again.

Comment: Check the given code snippet it doesn't show something like that. @Matjaz

Comment: this is what i'm talking about. https://www.hizliresim.com/hf2h2c6

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored your code and broke it down and remade it. i've made the logic simpler and more like an actual game loop [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3gfac6o5/)

```html
<head>
  <title>Farm clicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

```js
// global state
let game_state = {
    gold: 50,
  animals: {
    goats: 0,
    pigs: 0,
    cows: 0
  },
}

// global variables
const content = document.getElementById("content");
let passiveGoldInterval = null;

// helper functions
function addGold(value){
    game_state.gold += value;
  updateUI();
}

function buyAnimal(animal){
    switch(animal){
      case 'goat':
          if(game_state.gold >= 50){
                    addGold(-50);
                game_state.animals.goats++;
          }
          break;
      case 'pig':
          if(game_state.gold >= 90){
                    addGold(-90);
                game_state.animals.pigs++;
          }
          break;
      case 'cow':
          if(game_state.gold >= 120){
                    addGold(-120);
                game_state.animals.cows++;
          }
          break;
        default: // do nothing
  }
  updateUI();
}

// background function
function passiveGold(){    
        addGold(game_state.animals.goats * 5); // add gold for goats
        addGold(game_state.animals.pigs * 10); // add gold for pigs
        addGold(game_state.animals.cows * 15); // add gold for cows
}

// game state management (init)
function init(){  
  passiveGoldInterval = setInterval(passiveGold, 10000); // calss this function every 10 seconds
  updateUI();
}

function updateUI(){

    if (!(document.getElementById("addButton"))) {
    let myButton = document.createElement("button");
    myButton.id = "addButton";
    myButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>addGold(1)); // add one
    myButton.innerHTML = "Add Gold!";
    content.appendChild(myButton);
  }
  
    if (!(document.getElementById("goldCounter"))) {
    let goldCounter = document.createElement("h2");
    goldCounter.id = "goldCounter";
    goldCounter.innerHTML = "Gold: " + game_state.gold;
    content.appendChild(goldCounter);
  } else
  {
    document.getElementById("goldCounter").innerHTML = "Gold: " + game_state.gold;
  }
  
  let itemBar = document.getElementById('itemBar');
  if (itemBar == null) {
    itemBar = document.createElement("div");
    itemBar.id = "itemBar";
    content.appendChild(itemBar);
  }
  
  // animals (display counts)
  if (game_state.animals.goats >= 1 && !(document.getElementById("goats"))) {
    let myElement1 = document.createElement("div");
    myElement1.id = "goats";
    myElement1.innerHTML = "Goat Quantity: " + game_state.animals.goats;
    document.getElementById('itemBar').appendChild(myElement1);
  } else if(document.getElementById("goats")) {
    document.getElementById("goats").innerHTML = "Goat Quantity: " + game_state.animals.goats;
  }
  
  if (game_state.animals.pigs >= 1 && !(document.getElementById("pigs"))) {
    let myElement2 = document.createElement("div");
    myElement2.id = "pigs";
    myElement2.innerHTML = "Pig Quantity: " + game_state.animals.pigs;
    document.getElementById('itemBar').appendChild(myElement2);
  } else if(document.getElementById("pigs")) {
    document.getElementById("pigs").innerHTML = "Pig Quantity: " + game_state.animals.pigs;
  }
  
  if (game_state.animals.cows >= 1 && !(document.getElementById("cows"))) {
    let myElement3 = document.createElement("div");
    myElement3.id = "cows";
    myElement3.innerHTML = "Cow Quantity: " + game_state.animals.cows;
    document.getElementById('itemBar').appendChild(myElement3);
  } else if(document.getElementById("cows")) {
    document.getElementById("cows").innerHTML = "Cow Quantity: " + game_state.animals.cows;
  }
  
  // display buttons if match
  // button container
    if(!(document.getElementById("buttonBar"))){
        let buttonBar = document.createElement("div");
        buttonBar.id = "buttonBar";
        content.appendChild(buttonBar);
    }


    // goats buy
    if(game_state.gold >= 50){
        if(!(document.getElementById("goatBuyButton"))){
            let buyButton = document.createElement("button");
            buyButton.id = "goatBuyButton";
            buyButton.innerHTML = "Buy Goat (50g)";
            buyButton.addEventListener("click", () => buyAnimal("goat"));
                content.appendChild(buyButton);
        }
    } else {
        if(document.getElementById("goatBuyButton")){
            document.getElementById("goatBuyButton").remove();
        }
    }
    
    // pigs buy
    if(game_state.gold >= 90){
        if(!(document.getElementById("pigBuyButton"))){
            let buyButton = document.createElement("button");
            buyButton.id = "pigBuyButton";
            buyButton.innerHTML = "Buy Pig (90g)";
            buyButton.addEventListener("click", () => buyAnimal("pig"));
                content.appendChild(buyButton);
        }
    } else {
        if(document.getElementById("pigBuyButton")){
            document.getElementById("pigBuyButton").remove();
        }
    }

    // cows buy
    if(game_state.gold >= 120){
        if(!(document.getElementById("cowBuyButton"))){
            let buyButton = document.createElement("button");
            buyButton.id = "cowBuyButton";
            buyButton.innerHTML = "Buy Pig (90g)";
            buyButton.addEventListener("click", () => buyAnimal("cow"));
                content.appendChild(buyButton);
        }
    } else {
        if(document.getElementById("cowBuyButton")){
            document.getElementById("cowBuyButton").remove();
        }
    }
}

init();
```

Comment: @Matjaz this is the best way to design your code, keep it simple and organized, don't mix the UI and logic.